# Running to memory issues with as3 using procedural logic, any tips how to prevent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

so, in a nutshell, my question is pretty much in title, I have my first big project and now after 11k lines of code in one big file I am running into memory issues after a while I have tried out my flash, slowly it slows down until I cant do anything, even if I always clear containers when I can and remove listeners when not needed.

procedural, for those who dont know, I have everything in big main function and within that hundreds of other functions.

oop logic feels a bit too big of thing to try and understand at this point, procedural so far has been much more natural to me...

any tips how to prevent memory from running out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need any object oriented programming to break it down.

Just apply a bit of logic of where you can group & separate things. Also, chances of repetitive lines of code is very high too.

So first of, start grouping lines. put them inside different functions & call them in main.

After you bring it all down to chunks, you can start thinking of grouping the functions into classes as well. But at the very least the first step should have brought your problem down.

Comment: thanks for answer :) this I have tried to do everytime when I can, also I now debugged it while I waited for answers, it was few listeners that hadnt had proper removal that stacked up and eat memory. Lesson: always triple-check listener removals. plus your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is hard to solve without using object-oriented programming. Btw, the C style of coding is usually called "imperative programming"... just so you know.

The bad news is, 11k lines of code in one file means all the code is inside one translation unit, so **everything you coded is always in memory**.

If you break it up into classes, then individual class instances (objects) will be created and destroyed on a requirement basis, thereby taking up as much memory as needed (growing and shrinking, not static).

Finally, using as3 as if it were C will hurt you in many other ways long-term. So please learn OOP and break up your monolithic code into objects.

Comment: glad it works now :) but loxxy's answer is valid -- look for refactoring opportunities, where you can save on lines of code.

Comment: okay, and thanks for answering, I´m sure to learn oop when it is time, but for this desktop application I think I´ll go with this way which feels natural to me :) also, accidentally removed comment, re-adding: so, I debugged it successfully, it was few listeners that hadnt had proper removal. so, lesson learned; be really strict and sure that you remove everything when not needed anymore, otherwise it´ll stack and eat memory in no time

Comment: Yeah, memory leaks are bad juju! Avoid them as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well afterall calling this a bad practice, you may not giving VM (virtual machine) a chance to breath... I mean If your procedures goes on busy everytime in a loop like thing polling states then with great probability the VM does not find the opportunity to **garbage collect**. Which is a disaster.

So do not poll events if you are doing. Try getting rid of the grand procedure (the seer of all :) ) and try another architecture which the central monitor procedure is **invoked** by event handlers **when needed**.

Then when you settle, sell your product and get rich. Learn oop a.s.a.p. :)